# Multiple patients in one table if they have 2 diagnosis codes then count them as 1

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 1 table, in this table are multiple diagnosis codes. Patient 1 can have 5 diagnosis codes in this table. I want to write a query that if a patient has both “depression” AND “anxiety” it will count that and give me a patient count in the query.

| diagnosis_description | patient_id |
| --- | --- |
| depression | patient 1 |
| anxiety | patient 1 |
| depression | patient 2 |

output:
1 patient

I’ve tried multiple things but i can’t get it to work. please help

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT diagnosis_description) = 2`, or `HAVING MIN(diagnosis_description) <> MAX(diagnosis_description)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT patient_id
FROM DiagnosisDetail
WHERE diagnosis_description IN ('depression', 'anxiety')
GROUP BY patient_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT diagnosis_description) = 2;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/G6TYnSVU

Comment: If a patient is diagnosed with the same condition multiple times, this will return incorrect counts. I would add a `distinct` to the `having` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INTERSECT` to get patients diagnosed with both anxiety *and* depression:

```
SELECT patient_id FROM DiagnosisDetail WHERE diagnosis_description = 'anxiety'
INTERSECT
SELECT patient_id FROM DiagnosisDetail WHERE diagnosis_description = 'depression'
```

https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-set-operators-union-except-minus-and-intersect.html/

Sohail Aslam's demo adjusted: https://dbfiddle.uk/zyHF1Kta

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally gather the patients meeting the requirement using the [HAVING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having) clause.

```
select
    patient_id
from
    diagnosis
group by 
    patient_id
having  
    sum(case when diagnosis_description = 'depression' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
    AND
    sum(case when diagnosis_description = 'anxiety' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

Comment: In Snowflake you can slightly shorten the SQL standard `sum(case when ...)` pattern as `sum((diagnosis_description = 'depression')::integer)`.

Comment: OR `sum(IFF(diagnosis_description = 'depression',1,0))`

Comment: also if your have duplicate diagnostics per patient this method mis counts.

Comment: I'd still go with the SQL standard way, easier for non-Snowflakers to understand, easier to migrate etc.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - Fixed the miscount by adding AND instead of +

Comment: I would never go the standard way. Because it performs poorly. So you are throwing away money so you can change DB pater because this one is what, too expensive?